# Error with JsInteropt with GWT 2.8

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

I have this class:

```
package br.com.frame.client.teste;
@JsType
public class TesteJsInteropt {

public int b = 5;
}
```

and my code JavaScript of head html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = new br.com.frame.client.teste.TesteJsInteropt();
alert(a.b);
</script>
```

When execute project, i am receive this error in console chrome:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: br is not defined

Comment: normally it should work, are you executing the script from the head or inside the body?  have you tried with a different namespace or  global namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the export it's not working. You should check that `-generateJsInteropExports` flag is enabled (exports are ignored if this flag is not on).
Also, please be aware of the async nature of the GWT script loading; your above code will probably not work because at the time you execute `new br.com.frame.client.teste.TesteJsInteropt();`, the GWT application is not fully loaded.

A possible solution for this is to invoke a native JS callback, from your app entry point, when it finishes loading.